# Why do I get ORA-01722: invalid number in my project?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to make a pass or fail system, where the user enters the id,number,m1,m2,m3 and clicks on submit to get pass or fail. I'm using DAO,VO,DTO to process the result but I get "INVALID NUMBER" SQLSYNTAXERROR . What is the reason?

```
 public int insert(StudentBO bo)
 {
     try
     {
            //get IntialConetext 
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            //get data sourse obj
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyLocalDB");
            //get con obj from jdbc con pool
            con = ds.getConnection();
            //create preapared Statement obj
            ps = con.prepareStatement(STUDENT_INSERT_QRY);
            ps.setInt(1,bo.getSno());
            ps.setString(2, bo.getSname());
            ps.setInt(3,bo.getTotal());
            ps.setFloat(4,bo.getAvg());
            ps.setString(5,bo.getResult());
            //execute the query
            int res = ps.executeUpdate();
            return res;
     }//try
     catch(SQLException se)
     {
        se.printStackTrace(); 
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return 0;
 }//insert
```

This is my table in database

```
 CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."STUDENT_TAB" 
 (  
"SNO" NUMBER, 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"M1" NUMBER, 
"M2" NUMBER, 
"M3" NUMBER
)
```

Comment: You need to at least show us what the `STUDENT_INSERT_QRY` query is.

Comment: private static final String STUDENT_INSERT_QRY="INSERT INTO STUDENT_TAB VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"; this is query and i got error in "int res= ps.executeUpadate()"

Comment: Show us the `create table` statement for `student` [EDIT] your question do not post code in comments

Comment: You have 4 number column in Table.....I think somewhere you are sending string rather number.Need to debug the same and check.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets this parameter:

`ps.setString(5,bo.getResult());`

which aligns with this column of STUDENT_TAB  :

```
"M3" NUMBER
```

This seems the most likely source of INVALID_NUMBER errors. You need to check what actual value `bo.getResult()` returns; then check the effect of using `setString()` on it.